# Exception gets caught only first time but not the second time

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

Implementing custom exceptions in a simple java program.
First time, I give invalid input, the custom exception gets thrown as per expectation but when I try to do it second time the application stops. why?

```
    try {
        int option = getQuote.ask("Enter the options");
        switch (option) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Current balance is " + user.getAccountBalance() + TvConstants.RS);
            break;
        case 2:
            optionService.addRecharge(user, getQuote);
            break;

        case 10:
            System.exit(1);
        default:
            throw new InvalidInputException("", CON.ST001, CON.ST001MESSAGE);
        }
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        throw new InvalidInputException("", CON.ST001, CON.ST001MESSAGE + "");
    } catch (InvalidInputException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getErrorCode() + ":" + e.getErrorMessage());
    }
```

Main Method:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Service service = new Service();
    try {
        service.mainMenu(user, new InputAsker(System.in, System.out), false);
    } catch (InvalidInputException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getErrorCode() + ":" + e.getErrorMessage());
        service.mainMenu(user, new GetQuote(System.in, System.out), false);
    }

}
```

Console:

```
Enter the options
2
Enter the amount to recharge: 
as
ST001:Invalid Input- Please select numeric value.
********************
Enter the options
2
Enter the amount to recharge: 
as
Exception in thread "main" com.exceptions.InvalidInputException:
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: In your service class, you are catching InvalidInputException and suppressing it. First time you might be throwing InputMismatchException .

Comment: Why don't you debug it?

Comment: from where "Enter the amount to recharge: " message comes from? You should take a look inside your addRecharge method. When you execute second time there is a different state that is throwing an InputMismatchException, then you catch it and wrapper in a InvalidInputException and throws it again. That's why you are printing a InvalidInputException error

Answer (score 0):

In order to catch the `InvalidInputException` in the main method you need to throw it in the service.

```
 } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    throw new InvalidInputException("", CON.ST001, CON.ST001MESSAGE + "");
} catch (InvalidInputException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getErrorCode() + ":" + e.getErrorMessage());
}
```

Remove the second catch block from here.